# Not able to save Image by downloading in python

Tags: python

I need to download a png file from a website and save the same in local directory .

The code is as below :

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

k = requests.get('https://somewebsite.com/somefile.png',stream =True)
Img=Image.open(k) # <----

Img.save("/new.png")
```

while executing it in JupyterNotebook

If I execute, i always get an error "response object has no attribute seek"

On the other hand , if I change the  code to
`Img= Image.open(k.raw)`, it works fine

I need to understand why it is so

Answer (score 0):

You can save image data from a link using `open()` and `write()` functions:

```
import requests

URL = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574169207511-e21a21c8075a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
name = "IMG.jpg" #The name of the image once saved

Picture_request = requests.get(URL)
if Picture_request.status_code == 200:
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(Picture_request.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per pillow the docs:

> :param fp: A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or a file object.
> The file object must implement `file.read`,
> `file.seek`, and `file.tell` methods,
> and be opened in binary mode.

`response` itself is just the response object. Using `response.raw` implements `read`, `seek`, and `tell`.

However, you should use `response.content` to get the raw bytes of the image. If you want to open it, then use `io.BytesIO` (quick explanation [here](https://mellowd.dev/python/using-io-bytesio/)).

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

URL = "whatever"
name = "image.jpg"

response = requests.get(URL)

mybytes = BytesIO()
mybytes.write(response.content)  # write the bytes into `mybytes`
mybytes.seek(0)  # set pointer back to the beginning
img = Image.open(mybytes)  # now pillow reads from this io and gets all the bytes we want

# do things to img
```